# How to inject custom code to mToken() of the lexer

Tags: antlr

Can I inject my custom code to mToken() by {} block in the lexer rules?

Comment: My answer below essentially answers your question. Perhaps you want to create a new question and ask how you could solve the real problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Since this `mToken()` method is abstract in the super class `Lexer`, which the lexer derived from your own grammar extends, you also cannot override it in the `@members{...}` section of your lexer.